# mysql join column if value is not null

Tags: mysql, join, notnull

i try to join 3 column from my table into one, if value is not null. this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles_map` (
  `rm_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username_a` varchar(45),
  `username_l` varchar(45),
  `username_u` varchar(45),
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`rm_id`),
   FOREIGN KEY (username_u) REFERENCES users(index_num),
   FOREIGN KEY (username_a) REFERENCES admins(login),
   FOREIGN KEY (username_l) REFERENCES lecturers(id_number),
   FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles_name(role_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i try to join username_l, username_u, username_a, because only one have value != null.

can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` is a technical term, meaning a cross-reference between two tables.  It sounds like you are just trying to select the one non-null value, like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(`username_l`, IFNULL(`username_u`, `username_a`)) AS `username`
FROM `roles_map`
WHERE IFNULL(`username_l`, IFNULL(`username_u`, `username_a`)) = 'admin'
```

Comment: both option are good, but next i need to use this like this:

    SELECT
        CONCAT(
             IFNULL( `username_a` , '' )
            ,IFNULL( `username_l` , '' )
            ,IFNULL( `username_u` , '' )
        ) as concat
    FROM `roles_map`
    where concat = 'admin'

how can i do this? i cant use new column ;/

Comment: See my edit.  Note that this will not be a great way to do this, because it won't make good use of indexes.  It would be better to reorganize the data if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to retrieve the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)enated value , you could do like this :

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
         IFNULL( `username_a` , '' )
        ,IFNULL( `username_l` , '' )
        ,IFNULL( `username_u` , '' )
    )
FROM `roles_map`
```

But if you want to store it in a new column say `username` , first add the column :

```
ALTER TABLE `roles_map` ADD `username` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Then use an UPDATE statement something like this :

```
UPDATE `roles_map`
    SET `username` =
        CONCAT(
             IFNULL( `username_a` , '' )
            ,IFNULL( `username_l` , '' )
            ,IFNULL( `username_u` , '' )
        )
```

To JOIN you could try something like this :

```
SELECT
    `roles_map`.*
    ,CONCAT(
         IFNULL( `username_a` , '' )
        ,IFNULL( `username_l` , '' )
        ,IFNULL( `username_u` , '' )
    ) AS username
FROM
    `roles_map`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `admins` ON
            `admins`.`login` = 
            CONCAT(
                 IFNULL( `roles_map`.`username_a` , '' )
                ,IFNULL( `roles_map`.`username_l` , '' )
                ,IFNULL( `roles_map`.`username_u` , '' )
            )
```

Links : [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) , [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: both option are good, but next i need to use this like this:

    SELECT
        CONCAT(
             IFNULL( `username_a` , '' )
            ,IFNULL( `username_l` , '' )
            ,IFNULL( `username_u` , '' )
        ) as concat
    FROM `roles_map`
    where concat = 'admin'

how can i do this? i cant use new column ;/